# Devise No route matches [GET] "/"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

So I'm wanting to use Devise with my web app, and everything tested out fine on localhost, but when I uploaded it to my ec2 instance I get the error ' No route matches [GET] "/" ' and I don't know how to solve this.

Here's my Routes.rb:

```
devise_for :users

resources :submissions

root to: 'home#index'

scope "api" do
get "/submissions(.:format)" => "submissions#index"
get "/submissions/:id(.:format)" => "submissions#show"
end

get "/submissions/:id/edit(.:format)" => "submissions#edit"
```

And here's my Gemfile, keeping in mind that I did try it with just gem: "devise" but that didn't work either.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'

gem 'therubyracer'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
 gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
 gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

 # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
 # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

 gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

gem "devise", :git => "git://github.com/plataformatec/devise.git"
```

Here is my routes.rb on my ec2 instance:

```
new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)        devise/sessions#new
        user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)        devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)       devise/sessions#destroy
       user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)       devise/passwords#create
   new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)   devise/passwords#new
  edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)  devise/passwords#edit
                     PUT    /users/password(.:format)       devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)         devise/registrations#cancel
   user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)        devise/registrations#new
   edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)           devise/registrations#edit
                     PUT    /users(.:format)                devise/registrations#update
                     DELETE /users(.:format)                devise/registrations#destroy
         submissions GET    /submissions(.:format)          submissions#index
                     POST   /submissions(.:format)          submissions#create
      new_submission GET    /submissions/new(.:format)      submissions#new
     edit_submission GET    /submissions/:id/edit(.:format) submissions#edit
              submission GET    /submissions/:id(.:format)      submissions#show
                     PUT    /submissions/:id(.:format)      submissions#update
                     DELETE /submissions/:id(.:format)      submissions#destroy
                root        /                               home#index
                     GET    /api/submissions(.:format)      submissions#index
                     GET    /api/submissions/:id(.:format)  submissions#show
                     GET    /submissions/:id/edit(.:format) submissions#edit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rake routes` to check if you have this route.

Have you runned locally in production mode?

If this problem still cannot be solved, you'd better paste result of `rake routes` then someone may figure it out.

Comment: I'm new to Ruby development, so I'm not really sure what you mean by "runned locally in production mode." I updated my post with the routes .rb that I'm getting back.

Comment: The app is running on port 8080 on my website, and I updated the default url options in my development.rb file with that.

Comment: when your app can run in production mode successfully,then deploy it to host

Comment: Now it fetches things like home#index fine in terminal, but I'm getting errors like "ActionView::Template::Error (application.css isn't precompiled)... I guess I should go research what production mode even is instead of taking this thread in a completely diff direction.

Comment: I will tell you, it's very simple

Comment: when we coding , for convinience,we use mode development,under this mode , everytime we request to server,server will compile files again.so if we changed some code , just refresh the page , the change will affect.But production mode compiled files just once , so you have to restart server to make modifies affected.When we deploy app to host like ec2 , it always run production mode.

Comment: I never used ec2 , so I don't know if ec2 need you to configure server enviroment . if you don't use passenger/unicorn , just use webrick, you can modify config/environments/production.rb , `config.assets.compile = true`

Comment: Yes, I'm webrick on EC2. But I understand what you're saying about development mode.

Comment: Okay, now the site is loading in production mode, which is good. Now I'm just getting an "ActiveRecord:: StatementInvalid (Could not find table 'users'). Does this mean Devise is installed incorrectly?

Comment: Come on ,you can read the error log. Could not find table 'users'.Means no database/tables.Databases won't deploy to host,so you have to create a database for your app,then `rake db:migrate`(if you have migration files),or create tables by yourself. if there has database . the problem will be configuration again

Comment: ah , you can rake db:seed,I think it is the problem,because you use devise

Comment: and back to the issue of database,I guess you use sqlite(rails default choice) as your database.so open config/database.yml,you can try to change it by yourself

Comment: I think I got it. Thanks for all the help, taught me a lot! And yes SQLite3

Answer (score 0):

run this at your root of your application and check whether it returns root route.

```
rake routes | grep root
```

Comment: It returns the correct root of home#index. But the app is still giving me the same error.